# I am CS-Cart beginner and can't update a page

Tags: cs-cart

I am new to CS-Cart and I have tasks to do for my current position. I don't know how to make changes to the website. I downloaded source code for safety but in case, if I mess up anything, I don't know how to back up that code. For example, should I change the layout in CS-Cart or do I need to change CSS files locally and push? Also, if someone can explain that do I need to change anything in PHP files and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

For php changes please use the safe way, hooks and details you can find here -> https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/core/coding_standards/hooks.html

In regards to theme please find documentation here -> https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/designer_guide/index.html